# Structuring an SQLite database to separate readable/writeabale data

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm writing an app that will allow users to read short stories that are stored in an SQLite database.

So far so good.

But now I want to add features that involve writing to the database (saving the Y location of a ScrollView so the user can pick up where they left off, bookmarking stories, etc).

Should I add these values to the `books` table, or should I create a separate table `user_settings` with columns like `id` (int), `story_id` (int), `y_position` (int), `bookmarked` (boolean)?

Note: I'm also thinking ahead to the possibility of storing stories on a non-local database in the future.

My other question is: do I need to move the database somewhere to be able to write to it? I'm using SQLiteAssetHelper and the database is currently at `/assets/databases/database.db`. I'm hearing some talk of a `/data/data/mypackage` folder but I can't see it in my project.

My database setup is currently as follows:

```
authors
    id
    name
    name_alphanumeric

books
    id
    title
    author_id
    collection
    body
```

If it's useful, here's my DatabaseHelper so far:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database9.db";
    private static final String BOOKS = "books";
    private static final String AUTHORS = "authors";

    public DatabaseHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // setForcedUpgrade();
    }

    // Getting all books
    public ArrayList<Author> getAllAuthors() {

        ArrayList<Author> authorList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Select all query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT id, name FROM " + AUTHORS + " ORDER BY name_alphabetic";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                // create new author object
                Author author = new Author();
                // set ID and name of author object
                author.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                author.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                // pass author object to authorList array
                authorList.add(author);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return author list
        return authorList;
    }


    // Getting all stories
    public List<Book> getAllStories(int authorID) {

        List<Book> storyList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Select all query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT id, title FROM " + BOOKS + " WHERE author_id = " + authorID;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Book book = new Book();
                book.setStoryID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                storyList.add(book);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return storyList;
    }

    // Get all collections
    public List<Book> getAllCollections(int authorID) {

        List<Book> collectionsList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Select all query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT collection FROM " + BOOKS + " WHERE author_id = " + authorID;
        Log.i("stories", selectQuery);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Book book = new Book();
                book.setCollection(cursor.getString(0));
                // Log.i("stories", cursor.getString(0));
                collectionsList.add(book);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return collectionsList;
        // not sure how to log collectionsList here
    }

    // Get story

    public String getStoryBody(int storyID) {

        // Log.i("stories", Integer.toString(storyID));

        String storyBody = "";
        // String storyBody();

        // Select all query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT body FROM " + BOOKS + " WHERE id = " + storyID;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                storyBody = cursor.getString(0);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return storyBody;
    }

    public int setScrollPosition(int scrollY, int storyID) {

        String insertQuery = "UPDATE " + BOOKS + " SET scroll_position = " + scrollY + " WHERE id = " + storyID;
        Log.i("insert", insertQuery);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(insertQuery);

        return 0;

    }

    public int getScrollPosition(int storyID) {

        int scrollPosition = 0;

        String selectQuery = "SELECT scroll_position FROM " + BOOKS + " WHERE id = " + storyID;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                scrollPosition = cursor.getInt(0);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return scrollPosition;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But now I want to add features that involve writing to the database
>   (saving the Y location of a ScrollView so the user can pick up where
>   they left off, bookmarking stories, etc).
>
> Should I add these values to the books table, or should I create a
>   separate table user_settings with columns like id (int), story_id
>   (int), y_position (int), bookmarked (boolean)?

I think you have made it clear that they are **USER** values, so it is very likely that a separate user table would be the better more manageable solution.

> My other question is: do I need to move the database somewhere to be
>   able to write to it? I'm using SQLiteAssetHelper and the database is
>   currently at /assets/databases/database.db. I'm hearing some talk of a
>   /data/data/mypackage folder but I can't see it in my project.

In all likeliehood the database has been copied from the assets folder into **`data/data/yourpackage/databases/dbfilename`** by `SQLiteAssetHelper` (*as I understand that's primarily what it's for. However I've never used it.*)  Such folders have limited access (normally only the Application (rooted device an exception)) so that could well be why you can't see it.

As such there is likely nothing required in the way of permissions for writing to/updating the database.